# Is there any possible way to manage IBM virtual cloud instances with Node JS?

Tags: node.js, cloud, ibm-cloud

I'm not familiar with how cloud integration works but I have been assigned a task to try and find out a documentation on IBM portal which would provide a way to perform some specific actions on virtual cloud servers (virtual machines) instances like create, start, stop, delete, restart, upgrade etc. So far I have had no success in finding out such documentation. Although all of this has been already finalized with api's on Node js with aws ec2, alibaba ecs, azure cloud, google cloud and oracle cloud. Only service we are struggling with is IBM. Before this was done with Terraform service in golang but now we are shifting to node js. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like there's a command line interface here which could be controlled through nodejs: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/vpc-on-classic-vsi?topic=vpc-on-classic-vsi-managing-virtual-servers-cli and REST APIs here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/vpc-on-classic?topic=vpc-on-classic-creating-a-vpc-using-the-rest-apis

Answer (score 0):

The available api docs are here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs?tab=api-docs
javascript APIs are not available.  The python, go and raw (curl) APIs for VPC are here: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/vpc. The vpc will include creating "instance"s within a vpc.

Unfortunately javascript is not currently available.  You can craft your own based on the curl or use the "ibmcloud is ACTION" command line.  All of the command line have json output.